# Is there an S4CMD version of --no-mime-magic

Tags: linux, s3cmd

I am using S3CMD successfully and the `--no-mime-magic` flag to have it use the same content-type as original source.

However S4CMD runs faster and I'd prefer to use it. I don't see any equivilant flag of `--no-mime-magic` though. Is there one maybe called something else?

https://github.com/bloomreach/s4cmd

https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd